# Closed form of an dark matter related Integral

Tags: integration

A calculation of the dark matter density profile in a dissipative dark matter model leads to the integral
$$f(x,\theta)=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{y\,e^{-y}\,dy}{\sqrt{x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2\cos{2\theta}}}.$$
Is it possible to calculate this integral in a closed form? What is its limit in the $x\ll 1$ case?

Comment: Asymptotics for fixed $\theta\ne \pi/2+\pi k$ and small positive $x$ is $-\log x+O(1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote $y=tx$, we get a Laplace transform $$f(x,\theta)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^4+2t^2\cos 2\theta+1}}e^{-xt}dt.$$
Integral over $[0,1]$ is bounded uniformly in $x$, and for $[1,\infty)$ we have
$$
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^4+2t^2\cos 2\theta+1}}e^{-xt}dt=
\int_{1}^\infty \frac1t e^{-xt}dt+\int_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^4+2t^2\cos 2\theta+1}}-\frac1t\right)e^{-xt}dt.
$$
The second term is again uniformly bounded, since the expression in brackets decays as $1/t^2$. Next,
$$\int_{1}^\infty \frac1t e^{-xt}dt=\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-s}}sds=\int_x^1\frac1sds+\int_x^1\frac{e^{-s}-1}sds+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-s}}sds,$$
the second and the third terms are uniformly bounded and the first term equals $-\log x$. Thus, $f(x,\theta)=-\log x+O(1)$ when $\theta$ is fixed (and $\cos 2\theta\ne -1$).

Comment: A nice trick to obtain the estimate on the integral $\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-s}}{s}ds$ is via L'Hôpital's rule:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-s}}{s}ds}{\log x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-e^{-x}/x}{1/x} = \lim_{x\to 0}-e^{-x}=-1$$

Comment: @T.Le Of course, but it gives slightly worse result than $-\log x+O(1)$